# SVG or Canvas: Fill/shade overlapping region of 2 circles

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I'm trying to find a way to fill in a region of two arbitrarily overlapping circles.

In the tool I'm working on a user can create circles and drag them around on the screen. If two or more circles are overlapping the user can select the overlapping region (think Venn Diagram-ish). I need to fill in the overlapping region with a color or gradient.

Is this possible using SVG and/or Canvas in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way:

1. I used easeljs (html5 canvas) draw the 2 circles normally
2. draw the 2 circles again in a separate container using a
   compositeOperation of "destination-in"
3. cache the container (otherwise the composite operation will blow away the whole image)
4. add the cached container to the stage

code:

```
var s1 = new createjs.Shape(), 
    s2 = new createjs.Shape(), 
    s3 = new createjs.Shape(),
    s4 = new createjs.Shape(),
    c1 = new createjs.Container(),
    c2 = new createjs.Container(),
    container = new createjs.Container();

s1.graphics.ss(2).beginStroke("black").beginLinearGradientFill(["#f6f6f6","#e5e5e5"],[0,1],0,-40,0,40).drawCircle(0,0,40);
s1.x = s1.y = 80;
c1.addChild(s1);

s2.graphics.ss(2).beginStroke("black").beginLinearGradientFill(["#f6f6f6","#e5e5e5"],[0,1],0,-40,0,40).drawCircle(0,0,40);
s2.x = s2.y = 120;
c1.addChild(s2);

container.addChild(c1);         

s3.graphics.ss(2).beginStroke("black").beginRadialGradientFill(["#FFF","#0FF"],[0,1],0,0,0,0,0,40).drawCircle(0,0,40);
s3.x = s3.y = 80;
c2.addChild(s3);

s4.graphics.ss(2).beginStroke("black").beginLinearGradientFill(["#f6f6f6","#e5e5e5"],[0,1],0,-40,0,40).drawCircle(0,0,40);
s4.x = s4.y = 120;
s4.compositeOperation = "destination-in"
c2.addChild(s4);
c2.cache(0,0,220,220);

container.addChild(c2);
```